# Is there a way to simplify function signature playframework

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

Im using play2 and seem to do the following alot:

```
  def someFunction(request: RequestHeader) = {...}
```

is there a way to implicitly define the request so that I don't have to always pass it in to various functions that require having the request?

thanks.

Comment: What about making a class with `val request: RequestHeader` created on each request and holding all methods requiring `RequestHeader`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use implicits, that way you dont have to pass the request explicitly.

```
def index = Action { implicit req =>
   someOtherFunction("hi")
   Ok(someFunction)
}

def someFunction(implicit request: RequestHeader) = {...}

def someOtherFunction(otherArgs:String)(implicit req: RequestHeader) = { .. }
```

Comment: This seems to work when someFunction doesn't take any other args.  Is there a way to def someFunciton(implicit request:RequestHeader, arg:String)?  I can define but cannot call without passing the header in this instance.